# How to check if a certain theme option settings has already been set

Tags: theme-development

I am using the following lines to check if the theme setting already exist or set but it's not working:

```
if (get_theme_mod('mysetting')==FALSE) {
```

Aside from get_theme_mod, how to really check if the theme setting is already set? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `get_option` will do the trick

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

Comment: Would you please expand upon this answer? Perhaps provide an example of how `get_option` might work.